# Can get some counts in one sql query?

Tags: mysql, count

Good day.

Database: MySQL

**Table:**

```
name (varchar 200)
status (enum 'open','close','pause')
```

For get count all `name` with all status me need use 4 query:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM TABLE //count all names
SELECT count(*) FROM TABLE where status = open //count names where status = open
SELECT count(*) FROM TABLE where status = close //count names where status = close
SELECT count(*) FROM TABLE where status = pause //count names where status = pause
```

Anyone know how get all counts in **one** sql query and really it?

Comment: You need to learn how to use GROUP BY clause

Comment: @YourCommonSense but me need total count rows too...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT count(*) as total_count,
       sum(status = 'open') as status_open_count,
       sum(status = 'close') as status_close_count,
       sum(status = 'pause') as status_pause_count
FROM TABLE
```

Comment: thanks for information, i can accept only after 7 minutes. +1

Answer (score 2):

Use below query:

```
SELECT status, count(name) as cnt FROM TABLE GROUP BY status;
```

Comment: That does not get the total count

Comment: @TeopLome You can use the another query to get the total count or the subquery in this.

Comment: @BrokenHeartღ yes, i  can use it

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
Select Count(Status),Status,(Select Count(Status) as TotalCount From TABLE) From TABLE Group By Status;
```

Answer (score -1):

Another alternative:-

```
SELECT status, COUNT(*) as aCount,
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY status
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'All', COUNT(*) as aCount,
FROM TABLE
```